# My application receives memory warning even when there is no valid memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I am having this strange problem in my universal iOS app. While profiling the app, I don't see any valid memory leak in instruments tool. Still size of allocation keeps of increasing by 50-100 kb on every page change. Leak instrument only shows some leaks with Responsible Caller as mem_alloc.

After some time of usage, the app starts receiving memory warnings and some more time in the app and the app crashes. Interestingly, total memory allocation at this time varies between 6 to 12 MB. App doesn't show any stack information either, when I backtrace in debug mode.

I am totally clueless that why this crash is occurring. Any help will be appreciated.

---

Attaching some of the screen-shots of my instrument.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried with static memory analyser?

Comment: I don't have any idea about static memory analyser. Would you mind explaining me a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's been really long that I had asked this question and didn't get any proper answer. While visiting back to my question I think solution to this problem will be helpful for other early starters. So here I am posting my solution that worked:

Real culprit in this case was the way I was using images in the app. I was simply using it by calling [UIImage ImageNamed:]. Practically this method leaks the memory of image's size.

Solution to this problem is to use image by calling ImageWithData (see below code):

```
NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:extension];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It was unclear from the original post if you were using ARC or not. If you were using manual reference counting, how are you sure that it's not your handling of the UIImage files?  I have a hard time believing that an Apple framework class method has leaked memory in this manner for over 2 years, and gone unnoticed.

Comment: @mckeejm this question was asked way back in 2012, and that time I was using a non-ARC code. I would agree with your opinion that an Apple framework class method should not leak memory like this and I might be wrong in saying that it was leaking memory. Essentially imageNamed function caches the image data, that eventually eats up the memory. Also, if you search compare between imageNamed function and imageWithData, people will suggest you to use imageWithData.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for memory allocations with following in your app -

1. Using `Instruments` check `Allocation` and `Leaks`
2. Using Static memory analyser check static memory leaks.
   To use this either use "cmd+shift+B" or go to "Xcode -> Product -> Analyze"

Also you need to ensure proper release of your view controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have done the two things that you mentioned, and have asked the question only after that.

Comment: can you show some screen shot of your instrument, where exactly the memory usage go up.

Comment: give me some time and I'll post it here.

Comment: Attaching some of the screen-shots of my instrument. Can you please have a look and tell me if you notice something?

Comment: After seeing this it seems to be either your controllers are not released properly, or you are only pushing controller, never pooping them. Tell me one more thing are you dealing with some images also in your app?

Comment: I am using normal navigation bar based push and pop of view controllers and this is not the case that I am just pushing controllers. Also, the app have only thumbnail images in a list view and no other image handling/manipulation is there.

Comment: Seems I have found the resolution of this problem. The problem was with too much processing in a single go. The instruments must be showing me wrong trace/log.